# SQLite relevant user info retrieval

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am working on a login system using SQLite database. I already have a sign up form and it creates all users just fine and I also have created a method to check if username entered into EditText exists or not. But now my question is how would you go about retrieving all the relevant information from that user, for example I also need to check if the password of that specific user matches or not and I also need to retrieve some test scores from the user that are also in the database to then display them in the home page. Here is the code in main activity used to login the user:

```
public void loginUser() {
        EditText usernameInput = findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        EditText passwordInput = findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        String loginUsername = usernameInput.getText().toString();
        String loginPassword = passwordInput.getText().toString();

        if(loginUsername.matches("") || loginPassword.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fields cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (dbHelper.ifUserExists(loginUsername)) {
                //password verification and login
                //how to retrieve relevant users password and compare to password input?
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the method from databaseHelper that checks if the user exists:

```
public boolean ifUserExists(String user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USERS,
                new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_SAT_READING, KEY_SAT_MATH, KEY_ACT_READING, KEY_ACT_MATH},
                KEY_USERNAME + "=?",
                new String[]{user},
                null, null, null);
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()&& cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the number of ways that you could hanlde this is to have a User object that encompasses variables that hold the data. This inconjuction with a process rather than returning a boolean returns a User or null.

Perhaps consider this demo App based upon your code, which for brevity includes a User class within the Database Helper.

**DatabaseHelper.java** :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String KEY_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_SAT_READING = "reading";
    public static final String KEY_SAT_MATH = "satmath";
    public static final String KEY_ACT_READING = "actreading";
    public static final String KEY_ACT_MATH = "actmath";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String users_crt_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS +
                "(" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT UNIQUE," +
                KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT," +
                KEY_SAT_READING + " TEXT," +
                KEY_SAT_MATH + " TEXT," +
                KEY_ACT_READING + " TEXT," +
                KEY_ACT_MATH + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(users_crt_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertNewUser(String name, String password) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_USERNAME,name);
        cv.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
        return db.insert(TABLE_USERS,null,cv);
    }

    public User checkUser(String name, String password) {
        User rv = null;
        Cursor csr = db.query(
                TABLE_USERS,
                null,
                KEY_USERNAME + "=? AND " + KEY_PASSWORD + "=?",
                new String[]{name,password},
                null,null,null
        );
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = new User();
            rv.setUserId(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            rv.setUserName(name);
            rv.setUserPassword("");
            rv.setUserSatReading(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SAT_READING)));
            rv.setUserSatMath(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_SAT_MATH)));
            rv.setUserActReading(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_ACT_READING)));
            rv.setUserActMath(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(KEY_ACT_MATH)));
        }
        csr.close();
        return rv;
    }

    public class User {
        long userId;
        String userName;
        String userPassword;
        String userSatReading;
        String userSatMath;
        String userActReading;
        String userActMath;

        public User() {
        }

        public User(String name, String password) {
            this(-1L, name, password, null, null, null, null);
        }

        public User(long id, String name, String password, String satReading, String satMath, String actReading, String actmath) {
            this.userId = id;
            this.userName = name;
            this.userPassword = password;
            this.userSatReading = satReading;
            this.userSatMath = satMath;
            this.userActReading = actReading;
            this.userActMath = actmath;
        }

        public long getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }

        public void setUserId(long userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getUserPassword() {
            return userPassword;
        }

        public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
            this.userPassword = userPassword;
        }

        public String getUserSatReading() {
            return userSatReading;
        }

        public void setUserSatReading(String userSatReading) {
            this.userSatReading = userSatReading;
        }

        public String getUserSatMath() {
            return userSatMath;
        }

        public void setUserSatMath(String userSatMath) {
            this.userSatMath = userSatMath;
        }

        public String getUserActReading() {
            return userActReading;
        }

        public void setUserActReading(String userActReading) {
            this.userActReading = userActReading;
        }

        public String getUserActMath() {
            return userActMath;
        }

        public void setUserActMath(String userActMath) {
            this.userActMath = userActMath;
        }
    }
}
```

- Note the **checkUser** method is the equivalent of your **idUserExists** method but if the user isn't found then the returned User object will be null.

  - you should alawys close a Cursor when done with it.
  - Check a cursor for null, if it is returned by an SQliteDatabase method is useless as a valid Cursor will always be returned if the method returns.
  - Lilewise checking moveTofirst and the cursor's count is a waste if the count is 0 moveToFirst will return false only one of the checks is needed.

The above is used in an activity along the lines of the following, which reflects your existing code and the goal that you want to achieve.

When initially started the App adds a user (for demonstation) who's name is **Admin** and who's password is **adminpassword**. The UI consists of a textView displaying **Not logged in!!!!** (top of the display), two edit texts (as per your code) and a button for logging in.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    DatabaseHelper.User current_user = null;
    EditText loginUsername, loginPassword;
    TextView status;
    Button login;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        status = this.findViewById(R.id.status);
        loginUsername = this.findViewById(R.id.login_username);
        loginPassword = this.findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        login = this.findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginUser();
            }
        });

        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dbHelper.insertNewUser("Admin","adminpassword");

    }

    private void loginUser() {
        if (
                loginUsername.getText().toString() == null
                        || loginUsername.getText().toString().length() < 1
                        ||loginPassword.getText().toString() == null
                        || loginPassword.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fields cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if ((current_user = dbHelper.checkUser(loginUsername.getText().toString(),loginPassword.getText().toString())) != null) {
            loginUsername.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loginPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            login.setText("DO SOMETHNG");
            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Hello " +
                            current_user.getUserName() +
                            " you are logged in so you can do something!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            status.setText("Successfully Logged-In as " + current_user.getUserName());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

## Results

### Initial Run

[image]

- If nothing is enetered in either edit text and the **Login** button clicked then the ***Fields cannot be Empty** message is toasted.
- If an invalid user and passwprd combination is enetered and the **Login** button is clicked then the ***Incorrect username or password*** message is toasted.
- A valid username and password is input then :-

  - The text at the topd changes to ***Sucessfully logged in as ????!!!*** *(where ???? is the username)*.
  - The Edit Text's for the username and the password are removed.
  - The **Login** button changes to be **DO SOMETHING** as per :-

[image]